# transforming sigma notation into harmonic series. CLRS A.1-2

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-science

I've been studying algorithm analysis and the book i'm reading, *Introduction to Algorithms*, has given me a problem that i can't seem to solve. the problem is stated as follows.

"Show that $\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1} = \ln({ \sqrt{ n }}) + O(1)$ by manipulating the harmonic series."

where O(1) is a constant number (the solution below seems to throw away constants, since asymptotic analysis only cares about the highest terms).

i have found the apparent solution here: 
https://atekihcan.github.io/CLRS/EA.01-02/

buti can't seem to figure out line 3 where:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (\frac{1}{k}) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{1}{k})$$

from what I understood of the authors explanation, he or she is adding, then subtracting
 $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n$ to get the solution, but when I try to replicate the step the closest i get is this:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n \implies \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k+(2k+1)}{2k(k+1)}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$$
I'm wondering if anyone can help me see what i'm doing wrong, and if they know any resources to help me solving similar types of problems in the future (apparently i can't google hard enough). thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We see that the first sum adds the multiplicative inverses of integers from $1$ to $2n$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}$$
and that the second sum adds the multiplicative inverses of integers from $1$ to $n$, and then multiplies them by $\frac{1}{2}$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}$$
Note that these sums are different.

After substracting the first from the second, only the fractions with odd denominators survive:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n-1}$$
which can be written as
$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}$$

Comment: ok, i can see logically how $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1k-1}$ because the second term is literally taking away all the even denominators, but how would you mathematically arrive to the conclusion. how do you get the difference of $\sum_{k}^{2n} f(x) - \sum_{k}^n g(x)$: is there a way to manipulate $\sum_{k}^{2n} f(x)$ so that it equals $\sum_{k}^{n} f(x)$

Comment: @metalDS Well, the sigma notation is just a notation for a sum of values, for which you don't really need a proof or something to show equality (in my opinion). Anyway, for rigorosity you could use induction. Please tell me if I misunderstood your remark.

Comment: i guess if i just think about it logically it makes sense. my biggest problem is thinking about how the top limiting term of the notation is affected when the equation is manipulated: i have an idea that somewhere along the lines $\sum_{k}^n (f(x)) + \sum_{k}^n (g(x)) = \sum_{k}^{2n} (f(x)+g(x))$ since all the terms of both functions are getting added together resulting in 2n terms. anyways, thanks for the help. i have a feeling, i'm going to have to visit this site quite a number of times before i get through this book.

Answer (score 0):

Add $\frac 12(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\dots +\frac 1n) $ to both sides. ..

Get $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac 1k $...